# PCA with panel data in R

Tags: r, panel, pca

I want to apply Principal Component Analysis on a panel data set in R but I am having trouble with the time and entity dimension. My data has the form of

```
    city year x1_gdp x2_unempl
1 Berlin 2012   1000      0.20
2 Berlin 2013   1003      0.21
3 Berlin 2014   1010      0.30
4 Berlin 2015   1100      0.27
5 London 2012   2733      0.11
6 London 2013   2755      0.12
7 London 2014   2832      0.14
8 London 2015   2989      0.14
```

Applying standard PCA on x1 and x2 does not seem to be a good idea because the observations withing group (e.g. gdp of Berlin 2012 and 2013) are not independent from each other and pca commands like `prcomp` cannot deal with this form of autocorrelation.

I started to read into Dynamic PCA models but R commands like `dpca {freqdom}` which "decomposes multivariate time series into uncorrelated components". However, they require a *time series* as input. How can I apply DPCA or any other dimension reduction technique in this panel setting?

Comment: Have you looked into [SSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_spectrum_analysis)? Also, maybe It'd help to turn the data stationary.